# Custom object referencing Account when there is no access to Account

Tags: sharing-rule

Suppose I have `Account` as `Private` OWD (Sharing model).

I also have a `My_Custom__c` custom object that has a `Lookup` field to `Account`.

Provided I know the `Id` of a valid Account that I do not have access to, when i try to insert a new `My_Custom__c` referencing that Account Id, I get a `INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY` error.

Is it possible to somehow allow to create those records?

As a bit more context:

Imagine in one browser a user started editing `My_Custom__c` and in another browser some other user removed our first guy's access to the Account. i want the record save to succeed, even though they could no longer start that process from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

It's not directly possible, no. This is because if you were allowed to save the record, then [Implicit Sharing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_object_relationships_implicit_sharing.htm) might grant access to the Account for that user, so you'd accidentally provide sharing you didn't mean to. The system prevents this from happening by throwing this error. I believe you could set up a Platform Event, set a trigger on it, and then have some automation fire this event when a child record is created. However, again, if you attempt to bypass this error, you may cause records to be exposed inadvertently to the user.

Comment: Um, or simply do the DML operation in a "without sharing" class (if you don't use some form of implicit sharing in your org that would be affected)? This would, obviously, not be using the standard save functionality in a Salesforce form...

Comment: @PhilW As far as I can tell, this validation can't be bypassed using "without sharing." It appears to be validated at the database level, along with required fields, data types, etc. I had problems with this in a trigger some years ago, I never did find a way to bypass it, except to not set a value at all.

Comment: That is not my experience. Adding without sharing to the class performing the DML negates this error.